# How start next bash file only if previous was success?

Tags: bash, maven

In bash file `myBig.sh` I call another two bash files like this:

```
/bin/bash myBuildShortServer.sh
/bin/bash myStart.sh
```

It's work... but has one problem.
I want to start `myStart.sh` **only after success** execute `myBuildShortServer.sh`.

Content of `myBuildShortServer.sh` is this:

```
mvn install -Pruntime -DskipTests=true -f pom-server.xml
```

The bash file `myBuildShortServer.sh` just start maven tasks (goals). And when success finish tasks print in console smt like this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  30.254 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-06T12:05:43+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I need to start `myStart.sh` **ONLY** after `myBuildShortServer.sh` success finish.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first script is only this line you can try something like:

```
 myBuildShortServer.sh && myStart.sh
```

Of course you should make the scripts executable:

```
chmod +x <name of the scripts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to `myBuildShortServer.sh` a code to set the error code of the
script with the bash `exit` command, to propagate the error code
returned by `mvn`, like this:

```
mvn install ...
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo Could not perform mvn install, exit code [$rc]; exit $rc
fi
exit 0
```

You could then test the error code of the first script and avoid
executing the following script if it's non-zero.

Comment: If the `mvn` command is the last thing in the script, its exit status will propagate automatically. It's only if the script is more complicated that you need to add error handling logic.